# War file not getting deployed in JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf, jboss

I'm trying to deploy a war file in JBoss 7 and I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:   Source
>   Document: ...../jboss-as
>   7.1.1.Final/bin/content/ITSupportFinal.war/WEB-INF/lib/rewrite-integration-faces-2.0.0.Alpha5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
>
> Cause: Class 'org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewritePhaseListener' is
>   missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/ocpsoft/rewrite/servlet/event/SubflowTask

I have another project with similar Maven dependencies, same pom.xml file and this is succesfully deployed.

I have the following dependencies related to prettyfaces:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>ocpsoft-pretty-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>
            rewrite-integration-faces-annotations
        </artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Alpha5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Am I missing something? Or it's something wrong there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you got a missing dependency.

There is a similar post on the ocpsoft forum. (http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/cannot-deploy-project-if-i-add-integration-faces-2-0-5-jar/)